# tar.zip error during save

Tags: shell-script

I made a save script, to save some directories in my `/home`. To do that I loop through the directories in /home, and launch a save for each of them.

These directories contain jar files, and some `.txt`. Properties and other directories. The first time I launch the script it worked great. I modified it, but yesterday when I try some feature it goes wrong and I can not find why.

I have this error when I use the `tar -cjf` command to create .tar.zip archive.

> tar: home/myFolder : impossible stat: no file or folder of this type

```
backupdate=$(date +%Y-%m-%d) 
dirbackup=/save/$backupdate 
mkdir $dirbackup 
list_dossier=`ls ../home`

for server in $list_dossier 
do

    tar -cjf $dirbackup/$server.tar.zip home/$server

done
```

**EDIT**
I'm trying to keep this shape of save : a folder with name the date, and in it, X archves contain my X folders of my `/home`

```
#!/bin/bash
backupdate=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
dirbackup=/save/$backupdate
mkdir $dirbackup

for server in /home/*
do
    echo $server"test"
    tar -cjf $dirbackup$server.tar.zip $server

done

exit
```

Comment: Is that the _actual_ script you are using? There's a syntax error in the `for` statement.  There ought to be a `;` (or a newline) before `do`.  Also, you are much better off iterating over `/home/*/`, as in `for serverpath in /home/*/; do server=$(basename "$serverpath"); tar ... "$serverpath"; done` or something like that.

Comment: You may also have problems with your `ls ../home` results if the files listed have whitespace in their names, or newline characters etc.. consider feeding your for loop (or a while loop) a list of null separated results instead.

Comment: The `do` in my code was one line below, I have edit as my code is ^^
Ok for the `/home/*/` and yes you right @JeffH.I have a space after the server name !

Comment: I think `home` should be `/home`.

Comment: Any particular reason why tar's output file has a *.zip extension? I ask because *.zip files are not the same as bzip files.

Comment: I think you can choose the extension, if you want you can put, .tar.bz2 ou .bz. I'm using .zip because I'm actually on a windows, and to read it it's more simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line will cause problems:

```
tar -cjf $dirbackup$server.tar.zip $server
```

That's because `$server` would be something like `/home/myserver` and so this command would expand to

```
tar -cjf /save/2019-04-13/home/myserver.tar.zip /home/myserver
```

Note the extra `/home` in the path to the tarfile.

Instead we can change directory before hand..

```
#!/bin/bash
backupdate=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
dirbackup=/save/$backupdate
mkdir $dirbackup || exit
cd /home || exit

for server in *
do
    echo $server"test"
    tar -cjf $dirbackup$server.tar.zip $server
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your help finally got it ! Can you just explain me the `|| exit` ? Because exit is how to quit a script no ?

Comment: It just makes the script exit if the previous command fails, so if the `mkdir` fails then the script aborts rather than continuing.

Comment: Oh ok ! Thanks it's will help me to know that :D

Answer (score 0):

```
backupdate=$(date +%Y-%m-%d) 
dirbackup=/save/$backupdate 
mkdir $dirbackup

find ../home -type d -not -name "." -a -not -name ".." -exec tar -cjf $dirbackup/'{}'.tar.bz2 '{}' \;
```

Comment: There is no need to quote `{}`. Also note that this will be a pathname, not a filename. Using it as part of a filename would do unexpected things.

Comment: Yes it's working like that :) But I want to separate each folder save ^^  I have tried your code, and it's seems to "ignore" some files. I have the same error as the beginning but only for few folder ... :/

Comment: I have edit the question to update my code

Comment: **Up ?** please